# load php files as templates into div upon page load

Tags: jquery, ajax, templates, get, single-page-application

I am trying to create a single-page-application. Upon loading the index page, I want to load two php templates into their respective divs. One of the templates is a login form, and the other is a registration form. From what I have been reading - it seems I need to use an ajax "get" request to do so (as I can't pass two files to the jquery's load() function). Here is what I have:

application.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "templates/loginform.php",
        data: somedata,
        success: function(somedata){
            $('#login').append(somedata);
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "templates/regform.php",
        data: somedata,
        success: function(somedata){
            $('#register').append(somedata);
        }
    });
});
```

All I get is a blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
$.get('templates/regform.php', function(data) {  
    $('#register').append(data);
});
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out the errors...the page is still blank though.

Comment: which browser do you use? Look in the console, there you will see all errors that you have!

Comment: I use firebug...there are no more errors...it just shows the post and get calls that are happening when the index loads.

Comment: What is in the variable "somedata" ? Try to write `data: {}`, instead of `data: somedata,`

Comment: I was assuming that all of the data from the get request was stored in that variable to be manipulated...

Comment: No, in the `data:` you have to put everything that you want to transmit to the url. If you want to do a POST for example, you have to transmit the data as an object. So its working now?

Comment: so then what do i append in the success function?

Comment: The variable that you have defined in the success function.

Comment: If its not working, you could also use the $.get.. It should be easier... $.get('templates/regform.php', function(data) {
  $('#register').append(data); }

Comment: your last suggestion worked...thanks - i will update your answer and give you credit